# RegExp does not get replaced

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I tested the regEx on RegExr and it's working but when I put it in my code nothing happens.

RegExp: https://regexr.com/3gpfu

**My Code:**

```
$('.attachment-shop_thumbnail').each(function () {
    var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');

    imgsrc = imgsrc.replace('/-\d+x\d./g', '');
    console.log(imgsrc);
    $(this).wrap('<a href="' + imgsrc + '" rel="lightbox"></a>');
});
```

I tried to put it in a new variable:

```
var rgx = new RegExp('/-\d+x\d./g');
imgsrc = imgsrc.replace(rgx , '');
```

But that didnt helped at all.

Comment: Use the literal syntax: `.replace(/-\d+x\d./g, '');` or if you want the constructor version lose the / and escape the \ - `new RegExp('-\\d+x\\d.', 'g');`

Comment: Besides, if the `.` should match a literal dot, escape it, `\.`.

Comment: Thank you! @AlexK.